# Java - Casting to E[]

Tags: java, casting

When I cast to `E[]` (the class parameter), it requires me to add

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

For example:

```
E[] anArray = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

Should I be doing something different, or is it supposed to be like this?

Thanks

Comment: @Mehrdad Why should I be using C#?

Comment: Haha it was somewhat of a joke meant to address this problem (since `new T[]` is completely possible in C#)... didn't mean you to take it seriously. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad I figured, but I don't like C# due to only being able to use it on Windows, but that's beside the point.

Comment: Well there's always [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for every platform, but idk if it's worth the trouble.

Comment: It's not.  At least last time i tried it, Mono had issues...not least of which was crappy GC.

Comment: A lot may changed for the time, including new GC ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. Imagine:

```
Object[] o = new Object[10];
o[0] = new A(); // A is not a subclass of E
E[] e = o; // Now you have broken the type system: e[0] references something that is not an E.
```

The way it works, you have to explicitly cast in order to make the compiler ignore this possibility.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably read the [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) book.  In short, it is impossible to tell exactly what is the right course of action for you is because we don't know what you are doing, but generally you should not be suppressing this warning.  So most likely the solution for you is to use typesafe generic collections instead of arrays.

Comment: Using `ArrayList` as an example, it suppresses this warning, so what would using `ArrayList` over an array change?

Comment: see what @gpeche said.  Arrays are not type safe.  It's just not the way generics work -- compiler can't ensure that you are dealing with them correctly.  When using a generic ArrayList<> (not unchecked ArrayList!), you are staying in the generics type erasure world and compiler can still trace all types.

Comment: But `ArrayList<>` uses unsafe methods too. Here is a method from `ArrayList<>`
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E elementData(int index) {
            return (E) elementData[index];
    }

Comment: Well, the theory is that it was done and then verified by a bunch of Really Clever Sun engineers who have proven that it is safe (because the actual object array in private and transient and they full control over what is being put there, they can prove that any element of that array is of type E.  Basically, it is ok to suppress this warning if you can prove that it is OK and will be OK in all derived classes.  Which is Very Hard (tm).

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be doing that because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

To avoid having to suppress that warning, the only thing you can do is use a `List<E>` (or similar `Collection`).

Comment: As far as I know type erasure does not apply to arrays. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.8

Comment: See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType%28%29. This would not be possible with type erasure.

Comment: @gpeche I never said that type erasure applied to arrays, I was saying that the unchecked warning is being thrown because of it. The unchecked warning here is being thrown because the target type of the cast is a parameterized type. At runtime, only the type erasure of the target is known, so it cannot ensure the type safety of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are supposed to do it this way, since we can't initialise arrays of generics like this:

```
E[] array = new E[10]; // Compile error
```

You really have to do it as you wrote. There is no way around that I know.

---

Another approach is to use an array of Objects (instead of E). You can see that the Java API developers did it also like this inside the ArrayList class:

```
/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
 */
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

And they simply initialise this array like this:

```
elementData = new Object[size];
```

And everywhere they use it they cast the array content:

```
/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 *
 * @param  index index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E get(int index) {
    RangeCheck(index);

    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

I'm not really sure, but I think that the first approach is faster since the casting is not needed at runtime. The Java VM will spent some time casting it, I think. Why do I think that? Because this gives an error at runtime:

```
Integer i = new Integer(34);
Object o = i;
String s = (String) o; // Runtime error
```

So this means that the VM really checked if it **is** a String. But the fact that the compiler does *type erasure* makes me think it doesn't make any difference. Can someone clarify?

Comment: *Declaring* an array of a generic type is not the problem. `E[] array;` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The runtime will do a runtime class sooner or later and throw ClassCastException if appropiate. This is not C/C++ world and its undefined behaviour.